# How to waitForAlertPresent using regular expression in PHPUnit?

Tags: selenium, phpunit, selenium-ide

I have a javascript alert that says "The round is closed." or "The round is closed. You cannot do this action."

My code in PHPUnit right now is:

```
$this->waitForAlertPresent('The round is closed.');
```

The test passes if the alert is "The round is closed.", but if the alert is "The round is closed. You cannot do this action." it fails.

Is it possible to use regular expression for waitForAlertPresent? in PHPUnit?

I was thinking I could try waitForCondition and do preg_match, but I don't think it works because its an alert that pops up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How come you don't know up front what the text in the alert should be? Normally you should test against what you set it up to be. And if it is not the same, then the test fails.

Apart from that, something like...

```
$this->assertEquals('The round is closed.', $this->getAlert());
```

...should work for you. Have you found the [SeleniumTestCaseTest](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/SeleniumTestCaseTest.php) already? It show in great simplicity the possibilities of PHPUnit_Selenium.

And from what my own experience [Selenium2TestCase](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCaseTest.php) (using Selenium webdriver instead of injected javascript) seems to be more consistent, perhaps worth giving a try.

**EDIT**
I'm less familiar with Selenium RC / SeleniumTestCase, but `$this->getAlert()` should give you the text of the alertbox. Then it would of course be as simple as `$this->assertContains("closed", $this->getAlert())`.

But perhaps it would be better to also update your tests when you change your alert messages...

Comment: Oh. I forgot a very important part. I'm able to edit the alert, so making it 'The round is closed' would make it fail if I changed it to 'Round closed'. I just want to wait for the alert and see if it contains the word closed because sometimes the alert takes a few seconds to pop up